# ignore between characters while using a delimiter

Tags: python, json

I'm working with python and I want to be able to print off a file and separate the values. To add some context, I'm taking selected values out of a Json file, changing the values and then putting them back in. I can do every step...

But I'm having an issue with one of the lines of text...

```
"Hello, the date goes from {{exercise.start_date|pretty_date}} to {{exercise.end_date|pretty_date}}."
```

Basically the way that it's been done works with a workaround, but my question is, is there a way that I can ignore different sections, for example everything in between '{{' and '}}'

Then the output I want to get would be...

```
"HELLO, THE DATE GOES FROM {{exercise.start_date|pretty_date}} TO {{exercise.end_date|pretty_date}}."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this that come to my mind is:

```
st = "Hello, the date goes from {{exercise.start_date|pretty_date}} to {{exercise.end_date|pretty_date}}."

split_list = st.split()  # split the string into a list
for i, sentence in enumerate(split_list):
    if not sentence.startswith('{{'):
        split_list[i] = sentence.upper()  # make the word uppercase if it's not between '{{ }}'
print(' '.join(split_list))
```

Which will output the desired result:

> ```
> HELLO, THE DATE GOES FROM {{exercise.start_date|pretty_date}} TO
> {{exercise.end_date|pretty_date}}.
> ```

You could also achieve this in one line as [@depperm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680308/ignore-between-characters-while-using-a-delimiter/40680591?noredirect=1#comment68591260_40680591) suggested:

```
' '.join([word.upper() if not word.startswith('{{') else word for word in test.split()])
```

This will work as long as you won't have another `{{..}}` that you may want to be uppercase

Comment: In one line that's: `' '.join([word.upper() if not word.startswith('{{') else word for word in test.split()])`

Comment: Yup, that's correct. I also added your one-liner to my answer. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Nope, I was working on the list comprehension way but it was the same logic as yours

Comment: What about if I do have another {{...}} would it be possible to work around that?

Comment: Read my last statement carefully. Especially the last part. I was talking about the special cases where you could have {{word}}. In that case you'd have to do it using regex.